# Force to load child entity when making toList from an IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following code.

```
var query = from foo in context.bar.Include("qux")
            select foo
var mylist = query.toList();
```

When i try to access to foo.qux, it's not available !

So, how to ask Entity Framework to include the child entity when converting to List ?
Thanks by advance

Comment: It should be available. Is it your real query or is there any additional join or projection?

Comment: Is qux a navigation property?

Comment: Yes it's a navigation property without join

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Lambda Sintax, to avoid using the wrong name of the navigation property.
First you need to include the namespace System.Data.Entity

```
var query = from foo in context.bar.Include(x => x.qux) 
            select foo 
var mylist = query.toList();
```